# Is it possible to enhance CAPEv2 detection?

Tags: sandbox

I have used the Flare-CAPA plugin on IDA to help me with reverse engineering. Could I use these rules to enhance the detection of CAPEv2 sandbox?

In general: How to enhance CAPEv2 sandbox detection?